# How to setup Facebook autologin in Facebook web game?

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have an Angular application and now I'm working on setting it up on Facebook web games via iframe. All Facebook games that I have checked, already know your user information from Facebook and there's no button like "Login", etc. 
I have tried two options to login user via Facebook. Since app itself already have multiple login options, particularly via Facebook through Angular Firebase authentication, I've tried to launch Facebook login method in cases when app is open through iframe:

```
ngOnInit() {
 if (window != window.top) {
   this.facebookLogin()
 }
}
```

But in this case the problem is that Facebook login launching dialog window, and if user open app directly by pasting url in browser tab, browser blocks popup window by default. And I was unable to find, how to run facebook login without opening this dialog window. Not even sure if it's possible.

Second option I've tried, is to detect user through Facebook SDK by using getLoginStatus method. As far as I understand, since user is already logged on Facebook and opens the app from Facebook Games page, there should be some way to get this users data. I've tried next approach:

```
ngOnInit() {
 FB.init({
  appId: 'xxxx',
  xfbml: true,
  status: true,
  cookie: true,
  version: 'v5.0'
 });
 FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
 });
}
```

But this case also didn't work. Since I'm receiving 'Unknown' as an response from this method.
Is it possible to setup autologin for web app in Facebook games? I really didn't find any game that was asking to login user, they already have users data. And I couldn't find any proper information for this case.
Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: _“and if user open app directly by pasting url in browser tab”_ - then `window != window.top` should _not_ be true in the first place, so this should not trigger login _in that place_ either.

Comment: You will need to trigger an explicit login anyway, for any user that has not used your app before already. Only if a user has logged in to your app before, you can automatically recognize them as a recurring user.

Comment: @CBroe, it's triggering if you are pasting the url exactly of facebook game. As for 'need to trigger anyway'. Then how other games getting user data if I haven't login in them before and playing for a first time? I didn't click any buttons except "Play now" on game preview, and there also was no dialog windows.

Comment: It wasn’t clear what URL you actually meant. Well, yes, in that case it is supposed to trigger. But if you are in a Facebook canvas, then calling `FB.login` should not trigger an actual popup to begin with, it will display an overlay dialog instead (and that won’t get blocked). So the question now would be, what `this.facebookLogin` actually does.

Comment: @CBroe, this.facebookLogin() basically triggering service with facebook login method from angular fire library.
`constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { }

async loginFb() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return result;
  }`

Comment: Okay, but I have no clue what this actually results in, in the end … You’d have to check, if this actually calls the FB SDK’s own `FB.login` method at some point, or does something else. It needs to use that method, if you want to get the same page overlay, instead of the popup. If it doesn’t, and you want to keep using what you are using, then the only viable option is to not try any “automatic” login (rather bad UX anyway), but have the user explicitly trigger this via a click, so that the popup blocker will let it through.

Comment: @CBroe, ok gonna try to check login via native SDK.